# Catch output of several piped commands

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

Till today I was always able to find answer for my all bash questions. But now I stuck. I am testing 20TB RAID6 configuration working on LSI 9265.

I wrote script to create files from /dev/urandom and I am creating second to calculate md5 from all files with two addons.
One is to use time command to calculate md5sum execution time
Second is use pv command to show progress of each md5sum command

My command looks like this:

```
filename="2017-03-13_12-38-08"
/usr/bin/time -f "real read %E" pv $filename | md5sum | sed "s/-/$filename /"
```

This is example terminal printout:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "real read %E" pv $i | md5sum | sed "s/-/$i/"
1GiB 0:00:01 [ 551MiB/s] [==================================================================================================>] 100%
real read 0:01.85
f561af8cc0927967c440fe2b39db894a  2017-03-13_12-38-08
```

And I want to log it to file. I failed all tries using 2>&1, using tee, using brackets. I know pv uses stdErr but this doesnt help in finding solution. I can only catch "f561af8cc0927967c440fe2b39db894a  2017-03-13_12-38-08_done"
which is not enough.

Comment: Can you show us the commands you're actually trying to pipe to a file? Those should work.

Comment: these are commands I tried to put output to file: 

/usr/bin/time -f "real read %E" pv $filename | md5sum | sed "s/-/$filename /" > output 2>&1

And I just found solution
(time pv -f $i | md5sum | sed "s/-/$i/") 2>&1 | tee output.log
or equivalent but without printing into terminal only file output.log
(time pv -f $i | md5sum | sed "s/-/$i/") > output.log 2>&1

Comment: You have correctly found the problem, namely that you need to wrap the commands you want to pipe in brackets, otherwise you'll only get output from the last command. You should post that as an answer below and mark it as such!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
(time pv -f $filename | md5sum | sed "s/-/$filename/") 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

or equivalent but without printing into terminal only file to output.log

```
(time pv -f $filename | md5sum | sed "s/-/$filename/") > output.log 2>&1
```